# Unable to add macro to ribbon

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a macro which converts mins to HR: MM format. However when I try to add this macro to ribbon I do not see this macro under the "Macro" Tab. Can anyone help me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer

If TextBox1.Value = Empty Then

    MsgBox "You did not enter any value", vbCritical, "No entry"

Else

    a = TextBox1.Value * 7
    b = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(a, 60)
    c = a - (b * 60)

    TextBox2.Value = b
    TextBox3.Value = c

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. What ribbon are you using? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to add the macro as a shortcut in the Excel Ribbon to enable it to use for any excel sheet open.

Comment: Is the macro defined by `Sub` or by `Function`? Also, is anything being defined in it (e.g. `Sub Change(rng as Range)` v. `Sub Change()`)? Also what version of Excel is it (assuming 2016)?

Comment: I have added the code in the question, please suggest

Comment: I would try removing `Private` from your declaration and change `CommandButton1_Click` to something not referencing an object on the sheet, for example `Sub ChangeTimeFormat()`. `Private` itself will keep it from showing up in the Macro list for the ribbon, as would any reference to specific objects (`TextBox1`, `CommandButton`). Is this meant to grab a value from any sheet and change it, or to work with a specific object in a specific workbook? If the former, unless the worksheet has the specified objects, the macro will error out for sure.

Comment: Thank for the info. FOX. the form does not have any dependency with data from sheet. It completely works with the user input. Is there any way this macro can be added to the ribbon or add-in which would enable it to be used in any workbook?

Comment: @J.Fox: This means that we cannot have a macro added to the ribbon or as an Add-in if it has a form in use? Any other way by which this can be achieved?

Comment: If the macro is written so that it has a userform associated with it, you can add it to the ribbon on your machine by putting the macro and the userform in the personal.xlsb file (see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790 if you are unfamiliar). If your textboxes are all on a userform that pops up, that should work. If that doesn't make sense let me know.